# Cron job to run every first or last chosen day of week of every month

Tags: cron

I have a form where user chooses when to run a script. I've `fields {time,day of week, first/last}`. Now when the user chooses for example: 10:45 AM every first Monday - Which means run script on every first Monday of every month, how can I convert this to cron job.

Thanks.

Comment: Answer below, but this belongs on superuser, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the day-of-month and day-of-week fields in a crontab entry are ORed together rather than ANDed.  So you can't really do a "first Monday of the month" with crontab fields alone; you need additional logic. You could do something like this:

```
min hr 1-7 * * [ `date +%w` -eq 1 ] && first-monday.sh
```

Finding the last instance of a weekday is a bit trickier since it depends on how many days are in the month:

```
min hr 25-31 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 * [ `date +%w` -eq 5 ] && last-friday.sh
min hr 24-30 4,6,9,11        * [ `date +%w` -eq 5 ] && last-friday.sh
min hr 22-28 2               * [ `date +%w` -eq 5 ] && last-friday.sh
```

On leap years in which February 29th falls on Friday, that last entry will actually run the script on the 22nd instead, but since cron jobs can't specify a year, that's about as close as you can get.

Comment: Thanks, but what would it be for say last Friday? Also is it right that for First I just have to plugin day of week for the other days. Example min hr 1-7 * 3 for Wednesday?

Comment: @zulq edited the example to do last friday.  The last column before the command to run is the number of the weekday: 0=Sunday through 6=Saturday.

Comment: `min hr 1-7 * 1  first-monday.sh` will actually execute the first 7 days of the month and every Monday. This website (https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html) gives the following note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields - day of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time. For example, "30 4 1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.

Comment: Thanks, @StevenMortimer.  Updated.