# Running APScheduler Job Every nth Day of Month

Tags: python, cron, apscheduler

I'm looking for an APScheduler trigger that will execute a job every nth day of a month. For example, I want to run a job on the first Tuesday of every month. Or on the first and third Monday of every month.

Does anyone have a trigger that accomplishes this? You can *almost* do it with the cron scheduler and having your function double-check that it's running at the right time: [Cron job to run every first or last chosen day of week of every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498505/cron-job-to-run-every-first-or-last-chosen-day-of-week-of-every-month)

Comment: You could mark the answer as accepted, it's good manners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the documentation of the [cron trigger](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html#expression-types):

```
scheduler.add_job(func, 'cron', day='1st tue')
scheduler.add_job(func, 'cron', day='1st mon,3rd mon')
scheduler.add_job(func, 'cron', day='1st fri,last fri')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... somehow I missed this in the docs. One other question which I think is "impossible" in APScheduler. Can I schedule a job 24 hours before say the 1st and 3rd Wed of the month? The problem of course is that it could be the 1st, 4th or 5th Tue of the month :-\

Comment: I don't know of a scheduler that can do magic like this. But you can borrow code from the cron trigger and write your own.